# PFSense: Subnet can not communicate to the outside

Tags: networking, routing, router, subnet, pfsense

I have multiple subnets on a hypervisor with four Ethernet ports. Two are called subnets. Both of them are utilizing a NordVPN tunnel as their default gateway.

The first subnet LAN can talk to everything, even the internet.

Devices on the second subnet of OPT5 can't communicate outside their subnet's gateway.

The firewall rules and network address translation are usually the first suspects when this happens. I have drawn three conclusions after illustrating my ping test, packet captures, and firewall rules and drawing three conclusions.

- The WAN, NordVPN and primary router are configured appropriately as
  demonstrated by the success of LAN.
- The Firewall has allow all on all interfaces. No reason to suspect.
- Devices on the OPT5 interface can ping any devices within it's own
  network
- Devices on the OPT5 interface can NOT ping any devices on any other
  subnet
- Devices on the OPT5 interface can NOT ping any devices on the
  internet
- Workstation 10.0.4.2 can not communicate with any devices even within
  the subnet
- workstation 10.0.4.3 can

### MAP

- [image: map]

### Firewall Rules - WAN

- [image: firewall rules - WAN]

### Firewall Rules, OPT5

- [image: firewall rules- OPT5]

### NAT

- [image: NAT]

### Firewall Rules Hit:

- [image: Firewall Rules Hit]

**UPDATE**

Earlier there was a comment that said the solution would be to create static routes. I have confirmed that creating static routes is not necessary and the issue is with a PFSense setting dealing with 10.0.4.0/24 specifically. I did this by creating a replacement network address for my second subnet. The network address is 10.0.6.0/24. I have confirmed everything works as expected. However, I want my 10.0.4.0/24 subnet to communicate across itself as well.

Comment: Home and Enduser Questions are offtopic on serverfault. please ask on superuser.com

Comment: What is a called subnet? Sorry, but I'm not able to understand your problem. Please rewrite your question. You are mixing different terms.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple network interfaces and a few VPN tunnels you probably need to configure a routing protocol or static routing.
To send the right traffic over the right interface.

Your story is quite long,can just summarize which traffic needs to over which interface. And which VPN is mapped to which interface